# Oracle returns value in 2 tables

Tags: sql, oracle

currently I'm facing a problem where I select the data from db where it returns the data into 2 tables.

I have attached a screenshot of the output. Hope you guys can help. Thanks

This is [Screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5H3M3.png)

Comment: You should edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that those answering this question will have something to work. Also let us know what you've tried, what went wrong, and anything else you can think of that would help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to format the output in the SQL*Plus to make the output looks proper.

You can use

```
COLUMN <column_name> FORMAT <format>;
```

for string:

```
COLUMN SCENE_NAME FORMAT a15
```

Example for numbers:

```
COLUMN SCENE_ID FORMAT 99
```

For more details on column formatting, please refer Oracle documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/server/doc/SP33/ch4.htm)

Also, you will need to set the `LINESIZE` using

```
set linesize 250
```

here, 250 means the total character that can fit into one line and the size of the character is calculated based on the column format.

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks Tejash!

Answer (score 0):

Before that you mention which database table you will display. After do select query